# insert contents of 1 to 20 text areas into table (Oracle app server 10g)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms, oas

I  have an Oracle Application Server (10g) package that basically displays rows of data that users can edit after clicking an edit button.  The edit page contains 1 to 20 text fields.  It was working great using owa_util.ident_arr until the users needed to insert more than the ident_arr varchar2(30) character limit.

Now that I can't use ident_arr, I am trying to figure out how to insert the contents of the text areas (htp.formtextareaopen) into a table.  As I said, the edit page can have 1 to 20 text fields in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your implementation I should say you need to create your own collection type. First check from the documentation what owa_util.ident_arr really is:

```
type ident_arr is table of varchar2(30) index by binary_integer;
```

What you need to do is then create your own collection with a table of varchar2:s greater then 30 as e.g.

```
type my_arr is table of varchar2(255) index by binary_integer;
```

Comment: defining my_arr as you explained and doing a find/replace of indent_arr for my_arr solved the problem.  Thanks!